# Creating a connection with hsqldb

Tags: java, hsqldb

I have to connect a database to a java program. I'm using HSQLDB on OS X 10.7.4 with Eclipse Helios and SQLExplorer plugin.

This is the content of the runServer.sh file:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ../data
java -classpath ../lib/hsqldb.jar org.hsqldb.server.Server -database.0 file:mantenimiento -dbname.0 mantenimiento
```

You can find it in:

http://i45.tinypic.com/jfw6tw.png

When I executed the script this is what I get:

```
MacBook-Pro-de-Luis:bin luis$ ./runServer.sh 
: No such file or directory ../data
[Server@6016a786]: [Thread[main,5,main]]: checkRunning(false) entered
[Server@6016a786]: [Thread[main,5,main]]: checkRunning(false) exited
[Server@6016a786]: Startup sequence initiated from main() method
[Server@6016a786]: Could not load properties from file
[Server@6016a786]: Using cli/default properties only
[Server@6016a786]: Initiating startup sequence...
[Server@6016a786]: Server socket opened successfully in 7 ms.
] opened sucessfully in 505 ms.dex=0, id=0, db=file:mantenimiento, alias=mantenimiento
[Server@6016a786]: Startup sequence completed in 513 ms.
[Server@6016a786]: 2012-05-18 10:54:51.396 HSQLDB server 2.2.8 is online on port 9001
[Server@6016a786]: To close normally, connect and execute SHUTDOWN SQL
[Server@6016a786]: From command line, use [Ctrl]+[C] to abort abruptly
```

I have problems with cd ../data and then it creates the database and says its working but it is created in /bin and not in /data.

When I try to reate the conexion in Eclipse with SQLexplorer I get this:

http://i45.tinypic.com/21d3cl2.png

And the terminals says:

```
[Server@6016a786]: [Thread[HSQLDB Connection @60f47bf5,5,HSQLDB Connections @6016a786]]: database alias=mantenimiento does not exist
```

Anyone knows what am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: But I don't get the problem. When I do:

    MacBook-Pro-de-Luis:bin luis$ cd ../data
    MacBook-Pro-de-Luis:data luis$ 

It works.

Answer (score 0):

```
No such file or directory ../data
```

Create the `../data` directory: it doesn't exist. So obviously, you can't `cd` into it.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your folder structure, you'll see that the runServer.sh file sits one level behind the bin folder. Yet, the .sh script tries to go BACK one level to find the ../data folder, the .. means go back one folder.

Try changing the ../data to just data and see what happens.